# "this" does not return the selector

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a simple library to select an element and return the object of element.

```
(function() {
    var $ = function(parameter) {
        return new js(parameter);
    };

    var js = function(parameter) {
        var selector;
        selector = document.getElementById(parameter);
        this = selector; // assign selector to this.

        return this;
    };

    // Extend the library.
    $.fn = js.prototype = {
        hide: function() {
            this.style.display = 'none';
            return this;
        }
    };

    if (!window.$) {
        window.$ = $;
    }
})();
```

When I use it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"> Hello world! </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('box').innerHTML = "Good";
```

Note:  I want to do like this [create a simple JavaScript library](http://www.codephun.com/how-to-create-a-simple-javascript-library-like-jquery/)
**What is the problem that prevent run the code ?**

Comment: You cannot assign anything to `this`.

Comment: @basilikum: `this = selector;`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you can't do. See Tibos answer.

Comment: @LionKing: That is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign stuff to `this`. The error thrown depends on the browser.

Instead, you could simply return the selector:

```
var js = function(parameter) {
    var selector;
    selector = document.getElementById(parameter);

    return selector;
};
```

This will override the general mechanism invoked with new and work even with how you wrote the code. Seeing how you're not using the function as a constructor, you could also avoid using new:

```
var $ = function(parameter) {
    return js(parameter);
};
```

Comment: `Error: Cannot assign to 'this'` is not really silent when executing it… It's no syntax error, though.

Comment: You could also avoid the whole function expression = `var $ = js`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, i fixed the fail silently mention. As for the other suggestion, i would assume there is some more code, otherwise the OP could have done without the `var js` entirely.

Comment: @Tibos: But if I use your code, I think it is just like a function. I want to create a library not just a function.

Comment: @LionKing Yes, it is. This is not surprising, seeing how it **is** a function. Why do you think you need to use new/this ? Perhaps the problem is there.

Comment: @Tibos: I want to do like this [create a simple JavaScript library](http://www.codephun.com/how-to-create-a-simple-javascript-library-like-jquery/)

Comment: Too complicated an answer for this format i'm afraid.

Comment: @Tibos: Sorry, but I did not understand you. (Please see my answer again, I have been changed my code ).

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the selector to `this`, which is invalid, and you are creating an object that you don't need. Your code can be simplified as this:

```
(function() {
    var $ = function(parameter) {

        return document.getElementById(parameter);
    };

    if (!window.$) {
        window.$ = $;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Since we're cutting out pieces of the OP's code, perhaps we could optimize it to this one line: `window.$ = window.$ || document.getElementById.bind(document);`

Comment: Nice! I like conciseness... improve your answer